# Is this formula for calulating the energy requirements of pets applicable to all animals?

Tags: zoology

[This website](https://vet.osu.edu/vmc/companion/our-services/nutrition-support-service/basic-calorie-calculator) gives the formula: 70M<sup>3/4</sup> = Resting Energy Requirement for pets in calories/day, where M is the mass in kilograms. Is this formula correct and accurate, and will it work for rabbits, mice, and guinea pigs?

Comment: There's a lot to talk about here, have you started with something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law to guide you a bit? Is anything still unclear to you after you read that page?

Comment: No, because the exponent "3/4" is more important than the "70"; "70" depends on among other things the units you use - your question has lots of subquestions though, and most of them are answered there; your title is about Kleiber's law.

Answer (score 3):

No, I would not use this formula for rodents. The "3/4-law" is usually used only for mammals with a mass of m>10 kg and was derived by Kleiber from limited empirical data sets. 
For mammals with a bodymass below 10 kg the prefered exponent seems to be 2/3 which was derived from the relationship of volume and surface of the body and heat energy as the main source of metabolic rate. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0007096.pdf).

Either way this are only approximate calculations I would not trust too much as exceptions occure frequently and also the age and/or physical state can make a difference.